# how to set default linker script with path on gnu arm eclipse project template?

Tags: eclipse, templates, eclipse-cdt

I'm studying eclipse cdt plug-in development use [gnuarmeclipse](http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/).

I added new template for c project.

this is a parts of new template.xml

```
<process type="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.NewManagedProject">
<simple name="name" value="$(projectName)" /> 
        <simple name="artifactExtension" value="elf" /> 
        <simple name="isCProject" value="true" /> 
    </process>

    <process type="org.eclipse.cdt.core.CreateFolder">
        <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)"/>
        <simple name="path" value="source/linkerscript"/>
    </process>

<process type="org.eclipse.cdt.core.AddFiles">
        <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)"/>
        <complex-array name="files">
            <element>
                <simple name="source" value="linkerscript/myprocessor.ld"/>
                <simple name="target" value="linkerscript/myprocessor.ld"/>
                <simple name="replaceable" value="true"/>
            </element>
        </complex-array>
    </process>

<process type="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.SetMBSBooleanOptionValue">
        <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)"/>
        <complex-array name="resourcePaths">
            <element>
                <simple name="id" value="org.eclipse.cdt.cross.arm.gnu.c.link.option.nostart" />
                <simple name="value" value="true" />
                <simple name="path" value="" />
            </element>
        </complex-array>
    </process>

<process type="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.SetMBSStringOptionValue">
        <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)"/>
        <complex-array name="resourcePaths">
            <element>
                <simple name="id" value="org.eclipse.cdt.cross.arm.gnu.c.link.option.scriptfile" />
                <simple name="value" value="myprocessor.ld" />
                <simple name="path" value="" />
            </element>
        </complex-array>
    </process>
```

The myprocessor.ld is a linker script.

It works well but I missed myprocessor.ld needs full path.

How can I know a path of myprocessor.ld being create?

thank in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should either specify the relative path '../linkerscript/myprocessor.ld' in the link.option.scriptfile, or add '-L ../linkerscript'

btw, please upgrade from version 0.5 to version 1.x, the old 0.5 is outdated and no longer supported.

Liviu Ionescu

[GNU ARM Eclipse](http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/) maintainer

Answer (score 4):

If crossing this thread in search of where the linker script (**.ld*) is specified -

**Eclipse Project Settings:**

- C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->C Linker ->General->Linker script

Comment: may save others time in future, posting if useful.